# How to input some PHP code in string variable

Tags: php, codeigniter

I using codeigniter. And for some reason i want to input this code to some variable in the controller. And later i Call the variable in view..

here is the code i wanna try in the controller

```
$this->data['data'] = "<label>Kategori</label>
        <select name='id_jenis' class='control-group'>
        <?php 
            $no = 1;    
            foreach($data as $row){
        ?>
            <option value='<?php echo $row['id_jenis']; ?>' ><?php echo $row['nama_jenis']; ?></option>
        <?php
            }
        ?>
        </select>";
```

Can i input this code in `$this->data['data']` variable?. So i can use the variable in the view?

I know that its more simple if i just use the code directly in the view. But i wanna learn some new case. hahahaha.. So please help me guys :)

Comment: Do you want to [`eval`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) that code ? That's most of the time a bad idea.

Comment: Why don't you try it yourself?

Comment: Use eval to parse the string. But its not the best way.

Comment: Why dont ju run the code inside the `<?php ?>` tags first, to generate all the `<option>`s, and then pass the complete string to `$this->data` instead? Or you SHOULD actually pass the `$data` variable to your view, then run that PHP-snippet inside the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not e good idea but CI let you to do this. You can do like this:

```
$data['something'] = "<label>Kategori</label>
        <select name='id_jenis' class='control-group'>";

            $no = 1;    
            foreach($data as $row){

            $data['something'] .= "<option value='". $row['id_jenis'] ."' >". $row['nama_jenis'] ."</option>";

            }

        $data['something'] .= "</select>";
```

In the view, you can print this:

```
<?php echo $something; ?>
```